# Select unique IDs from two DataTables with three queries and merge

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two DataTables that are populated from a database. One is the core data and the other is an audit table, that records when a record from the core data has been inserted, updated or deleted.

Note: deleted records will not be in the core data, but will have a audit history.

Ultimately I want to get out a DataTable of unique "ID"s with the latest "AUDITDATE" and then sorted by that "AUDITDATE" descending. Then I can have a DataTable telling me what unique IDs were altered last in descending order.

"AUDITDATE" and "ID" are both double datatypes with a format of "yyyyMMddhhmmss".

So I was thinking I could do three queries:

1. What audit records are in the core data (gives me what is
   existing)
2. What audit records are NOT in the core data (gives me
   what has been deleted)
3. What core records are NOT in the audit
   data (gives me what has not been touched)

   ```
   var setCore = new HashSet<double>(geometry.dtGEOM_TABLE_CORE.AsEnumerable().Select(p => p.Field<double>("ID")));
   var setAudit = new HashSet<double>(geometry.dtGEOM_TABLE_AUDIT.AsEnumerable().Select(p => p.Field<double>("ID")));

   var resultAuditInCore = geometry.dtGEOM_TABLE_AUDIT.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(r => new { AUDITDATE = r.Field<double>("AUDITDATE"), ID = r.Field<double>("ID"), STATUS = "EXISTING" })
       .Where(r => setCore.Contains(r.ID))
       .OrderByDescending(r => r.AUDITDATE)
       .GroupBy(r => r.ID)
       .CopyToDataTable();

   var resultAuditNotInCore = geometry.dtGEOM_TABLE_AUDIT.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(r => new { AUDITDATE = r.Field<double>("AUDITDATE"), ID = r.Field<double>("ID"), STATUS = "DELETED" })
       .Where(r => !setCore.Contains(r.ID))
       .OrderByDescending(r => r.AUDITDATE)
       .GroupBy(r => r.ID)
       .CopyToDataTable();

   var resultCoreNotInAudit = geometry.dtGEOM_TABLE_CORE.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(r => new { AUDITDATE = (double)0, ID = r.Field<double>("ID"), STATUS = "NA" })
       .Where(r => !setAudit.Contains(r.ID))
       .OrderByDescending(r => r.ID)
       .CopyToDataTable();
   ```

After this I was going to merge all three sorting again on "AUDITDATE".

Issues: CopyToDataTable() doesn't work, however it does when you remove the `select()`

Questions:

- How to get the three queries to output DataTables?
- Once the DataTables have been created how to merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do realize that the result of a `GroupBy` is a sequence of `IGrouping<key, items>` objects, don't you? Each group might have a different number of elements. Such a sequence cannot be converted to a data table.

According to [MSDN `System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) The generic parameter T is a `DataRow`. My compiler complains that the result of your GroupBy can't be input for CopyToDataTable, because your anonymous class is not a DataRow.

So we have to convert your untouched, deleted and audited items into one ordered sequence that can be converted into `DataRows` that contain the data you want in your table.

---

I assume the items in your core data table have at least an Id, and the elements in your audit data table have at least an `AuditDate`, and a `CoreDataId` referring to the Id of the audited item in the core data table (at least as long as the item exists).

Apparently you want all data into one table, I assume you'll have this data in a object `TableData`.

Because untouched items are not in the table of `AuditedData`, untouched items in the core table should have `TableData`.

All deleted items are not in the core data anymore, therefore deleted items in the AuditedData table also need to have `TableData`.

Because you want to order all data by DateTime, your `TableData` should also contain an AuditDate. Some items are never audited, their AuditDate is null.

*TODO*: decide how to sort with items that are never audited? First or last in ordered result?*

```
class TableData
{
    DateTime? AuditDate {get; set;} // used to order by date. null if never audited
    ...
}

class CoreData
{
    public int Id {get; set;}     // int may be any other type
    public TableData {get; set;}  // all untouched items should have this
                                  // all others: choose what you want
    ...
}

class AuditData
{
    public DateTime AuditDate {get; set;}
    public int CoreId {get; set;}
    public TableData {get; set;}  // all deleted items should have this
                                  // all others: choose what you want
    ...
}

IEnumerable<CoreData> coreData = ...
IEnumerable<AuditData> auditedData = ...
```

I guess You'll be able to create LINQ queries to convert your original core data and audited data into the last mentioned sequences.

**Items that are never touched (never edited nor deleted)**
= all items that are in coreData, but not in auditedData:

```
var auditedItemIds = auditedData
    .Select(auditedItem => auditedItem.CoreId)
    .Distinct();
IEnumerable<TableData> untouchedItems = coreData
    .Where(coreItem => !auditedItemIds.Contains(coreItem.Id))
    .Select(coreItem => coreItem.TableData;
```

**Deleted Items**
= all items in `auditedData` that are not in `coreData` (anymore)
we only want the last auditedData item

```
var coreItemIds = coreData.Select(coreItem => coreItem.Id)
    .Distinct();
IEnumerable<TableData> deletedItems = auditedData
    // take only the audited items that are not in core data anymore:
    .Where(auditedItem => !coreItemIds.Contains(auditedItem.CoreId)
    // group the remaining items by same CoreId
    .GroupdBy(
        auditedItem => auditedItem.CoreId,     // key of the group: coreId
        autitedItem => auditedItem.TableData); // elements of the group
    // from every group (= all audited items belonging to the same core item)
    // take the element with the newest date
    // = order by descending AuditDate and take FirstOrDefault
    // because a group is created you are certain there is an element in the group
    .Select(group => group
        .OrderbyDescending(groupElement => groupElement.AuditDate)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

**Edited Items**
= all items that are in both `coreData` and in `auditedData`, I'm not sure if you want the `tableData` from `coreData` or from `auditedData`. The LINQ query is similar.

Assuming you want the `tableData` from the latest audit:

```
var coreItemIds = coreData.Select(coreItem => coreItem.Id)
    .Distinct();
IEnumerable<TableData> newestAuditData = auditedData
    // take only auditedData that is still in coreData
    .Where(auditedItem => coreItemIds.Contains(auditedItem.CoreId)
    // group the remaining items by same CoreId
    .GroupdBy(
        auditedItem => auditedItem.CoreId,     // key of the group: coreId
        autitedItem => auditedItem.TableData); // elements of the group
    // from every group (= all audited items belonging to the same core item)
    // take the element with the newest date
    // = order by descending AuditDate and take FirstOrDefault
    // because a group is created you are certain there is an element in the group
    .Select(group => group
        .OrderbyDescending(groupElement => groupElement.AuditDate)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

Did you notice that the expression after the `Where` is the same with deleted items as in the audited items?

Now all you have to do is decide how to sort all these elements, and put them in one sequence of DataRows.

```
IOrderedEnumerable<TableData> OrderQueryResult(
    IEnumerable<TableData> unTouchedItems,
    IEnumerable<TableData> deletedItems,
    IEnumerable<TableData> auditedItems)
{
    // TODO decide what order to use
    return result;
}

class MyDataRow : DataRow
{
    MyDataRow(TableData tableData)
    {
        // in the constructor, extract the data you want in the DataRow
    }
}

IOrderedEnumerable<TableData> orderedTableData = OrderedQueryResult(
    untouchedItems, deletedItems, newestAuditData);
IEnumerable<MyDataRow> dataRows = orderedTableData
    .Select(tableData => new MyDataRow(tableData);
DataTable myTable = dataRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Finally, I'm not sure if your database already exists, or if you are developing it now. Your query is so difficult, because you have two tables containing the same data: one with your actual data, and one containing the history of the data. If you had the following tables, your queries would have been much easier

I write this in Entity-Framework format. If you use any other method, I'm sure you can extract the SQL tables from it.

```
class CoreData
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ... NeverChangingItems {get; set;}

    public bool IsObsolete {get; set;}

    // HistoricData is data that might change through history
    public virtual ICollection<HistoricData> HistoricData {get; set;}
 }

 public class HistoricData
 {
      public int Id {get; set;}
      public DateTime AuditDate {get; set;}
      public ... ItemsThatChangeThroughoutHistory {get; set;}

      // foreign key to owning Core
      public int CoreDataId {get; set;}
      public virtual CoreData CoreData {get; set;}
 }
```

If you would have a table  with unchanging core data and a table with the history, your three queries would be much simpler. Besides you won't need to have copies of unchanged core data, because elements are never deleted.

Note that in the method you use, deleted items are in fact also not deleted, because they remain in your audited table.

Comment: Appreciate your time Harold, will take a proper look at this on Monday